# How loud are guns in Pathfinder, really?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, difficulty-class, firearms

Related question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10989/how-do-i-represent-semi-realistic-gun-fire-fights-using-pathfinder-dd-3-5-cover), similar question about casting volume [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/50944/how-loud-obvious-is-a-wizard-casting-a-spell).

I'm playing in a game with a gunslinger ally, and while this hasn't come up just yet, I'm sure it will eventually. Are there any hard and fast rules for the actual DC value to hear a gunshot in Pathfinder 1e? I don't have access to the books right now, but the SRD table for Perception lists "Sound of battle" as -10 to the DC as the closest thing, and I couldn't find anything on the firearms page specifically.

**Is there any ruling more concrete than this for the sound of gunfire, or are we in GM fiat territory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### There are no special rules for the sound of guns

All combat is heard at a [Perception](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception) DC reduction of 10. While they did make a [wondrous consumable](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/oil-of-silence/) to silence guns specifically, it does not actually say they're any louder than the sounds of a swordfight or warhammer striking full plate. It's notoriously difficult to prove a negative, but I've reviewed the material as thoroughly as I am able and found no mention of guns in relation to Perception except a number of instances of trying to hide guns.

### Would it actually make sense?

Guns are indeed louder than general combat is likely to be; looking at a real world chart of (estimated) [noise levels](https://www.stac-uk.com/downloads/Noise%20Levels.pdf), a sledgehammer* runs in around 120 dB, not accounting for hitting hollow plate... probably closer to a percussion section (130 dB). *Modern* guns ring in at about 160 dB. From experience, I can tell you that muzzle loaders that most Pathfinder guns "simulate" were not nearly as loud. I would estimate them to be a bit more than half as loud as their modern variants due to the type and packing of the firing powder (about [10 decibels](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-levelchange.htm) less). Assuming 130 vs 150 dB, guns are still *four times* louder than their loudest allies' efforts.

*Unfortunately, I could not find any information about the sounds of using medieval weapons

### GM Recommendation

When I've played games with a Gunslinger, it has rarely come up how difficult it was to hear them. In the times when it did, we deemed it sufficient to drop the DC by another 2 (5 when it involved a [Modern Firearm](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/firearms/modern-firearms/)). It never caused a difference in the actual results of the rolls, as everyone was able to discern the sounds of combat itself. I would only say, sometimes sound levels are hand-waved when the party ambushes an enemy which would not be possible if a Gunslinger fires a volley.